# Mysql query returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following query with subquery that returns no result

```
SELECT 'Message'
FROM message
WHERE ID in (
SELECT 'Message_id'
FROM user_message
WHERE 'status' =false )
```

Data in both tables is present. What could be the problem?

Comment: It should be `select message from message where id in ( select message_id from user_message where status = false )`. No single quotes but can have back ticks on column names.

Comment: @t.niese: I know that. But I don't think it is the OP's intention. OP unknowingly might have put that. See similar usage on other columns as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using  a sub-query?

Why not

```
SELECT Message
FROM message JOIN user_message ON ID = Message_id
WHERE status = false
```

Seems simpler

Comment: back-ticks should replace single quotes.

Comment: @Ravinder - I know. missed some

Answer (score 1):

You quoted the fields. Either do not quote the fields, or escape your fields with tick like this

```
SELECT `Message`
FROM message
WHERE ID in (
  SELECT `Message_id`
  FROM user_message
  WHERE `status` =false )
```

Comment: I prefer this solution.  It will not generate duplicates if there are multiple matches in `user_message`.